# Inconsistency with the way Matlab prints out the value of a variable

Tags: matlab

I'm solving some problems in semiconductor course for computing the intrinsic carrier concentration which are the number of free electrons in a pure material (i.e. no impurities whatsoever). The math behind the formula is straightforward but I'm not sure why Matlab shows different values for the same variable. In the following code, the variable ni at temp -70 (i.e. the first element) is printed out differently:

```
clear all
clc

B=5.4e31;
EG=1.12;
k=8.62e-5;
T = convtemp([-70 0 20 100 125],'C','K');
ni = sqrt(  B*T.^3.*exp(- EG./(k*T)) )
ni(1)
```

The result is

```
ni =
   1.0e+12 *
    0.0000    0.0016    0.0088    1.4554    4.7861
ans =
   2.7520e+05
```

For the first element, in the first method is zero but it doesn't seem that way internally as shown if `ni(1)` is printed out alone. **My question** is what is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: It's not zero; it's getting truncated, because it's so small compared to the other array elements that all displayed digits are zero. (Note the `1.0e+12 *` at the start.)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting `format long` then I guess you will see that in the first approach this is not zero as the number is truncated at some point.

So, put therefore `format long` in one of the first lines of your code before printing your actual data/vector and you will see.

Comment: As an alternative, I quite like `format longg`, which will use either `long` or `longE` (i.e. exponential format).